# asp-append-version attribute is not recognized when custom logic added to «img» tag

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

`asp-append-version` attribute works as expected when `img` tag has standard structure. I.e.:

This TagHelper:

```
<img asp-append-version="true" src="~/images/about.jpg" />
```

produces expected html output:

```
<img src="/images/about.jpg?v=4xCtMpE5CMcTYU8_S2HRr_MJIIbbF1CaFbx1p1doO4g" />
```

But when i add some custom C#-logic into `img` tag `asp-append-version` stops working. I.e.:

```
<img asp-append-version="true" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageId) ? "" : $"id={Model.ImageId}") src="@Model.Path" />
```

turns into html:

```
<img asp-append-version="true" id=imgAvatarEdit src="/images/upload/userAvatars/vdnf131s.jpg" />
```

What is wrong with code-snippets nested into ImageTagHelper?

Answer (score 1):

> when i add some custom C#-logic into img tag asp-append-version stops working

It seems be recognized as html `<img>` element while using the conditional operator `?:` in the element's attribute declaration area, which cause the issue.

To achieve same requirement, you can use `@if` to control when code runs, like below.

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageId))
{
    <img asp-append-version="true" src="@Model.Path" />
}
else
{
    <img asp-append-version="true" id="@Model.ImageId" src="@Model.Path" />
}
```

Besides, you can try to implement a custom [ImageTagHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f5b6039add50ea84ddb151cd6daf5207119dc116/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ImageTagHelper.cs#L111) to accept `ImageId` related information, then dynamically generate `id` attribute for `<img>` element.

```
private const string IdAttributeName = "asp-id";

//...

public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    if (output == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
    }

    output.CopyHtmlAttribute(SrcAttributeName, context);
    ProcessUrlAttribute(SrcAttributeName, output);

    if (AppendVersion)
    {
        EnsureFileVersionProvider();

        //...

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", Id);
        }

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute(SrcAttributeName, FileVersionProvider.AddFileVersionToPath(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase, Src));
    }
}
```

*Using custom ImageTagHelper and set `asp-id`*

```
<img asp-append-version="true" asp-id="@Model.ImageId" src="@Model.Path" />
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I have the same thoughts at the moment to write custom ImageTagHelper. But it is still interesting what is wrong with standard one.